# Draw GitGraph using a topologically sorted graph

Tags: javascript, algorithm, graph-theory, gitgraph.js

Is it possible to draw a [gitgraph](https://www.nicoespeon.com/gitgraph.js/#5.8) i.e. a graph representation using only `branch` and `commit` commands if my starting data is a set of topologically sorted `nodes` and `edges`?

For example, my nodes could look like:

```
let nodes = {
  {id: 1},
  {id: 2},
  {id: 3},
  {id: 4},
  {id: 5},
};
```

and my edges:

```
let edges = {
  {from: 1, to: 2},
  {from: 2, to: 3},
  {from: 1, to: 4},
  {from: 4, to: 5},
};
```

The end result would be a gitgraph with the following structure:

```
 3   5
 ^   ^
 |   |
 2   4
 ^  ^ 
 | /
  1
```

Essentially what I need is the algorithm that would organize my calls for `branch` and `commit` commands.